# What are the statistical probabilities of commercial aircraft accidents?

Tags: aviation-history, accident-statistics

Is there any study showing how probabilities of various kinds of aviation (e.g. crash-landings, fatal crashes, mid-air collisions) accidents have increased or reduced over time?

Comment: @RalphJ - True about the wealth of information. Not sure if this information is on Stack Exchange, though. Should I delete this query?

Comment: What is your definition of an accident? See: [What is the difference between aviation “accident” and “incident”?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14074/what-is-the-difference-between-aviation-accident-and-incident)

Comment: @mins - Accident as defined by ICAO annex 13. [http://www.iprr.org/manuals/Annex13.html ]

Comment: @RalphJ We prefer not to just [send people to Google](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/a/1552/62). Even if the information is available, many people have difficulty finding the right links and understanding them. That's exactly how SE can help.

Comment: @mins - Well, I was actually thinking about statistical probabilities. While boarding a plane, what are the chances of that plane being in an accident?

Comment: I'm sure the information is right here: See [this, for example](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8447/airline-safety-what-happened-between-1959-and-1962).

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer**

The [International Air Transport Association](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association) (IATA) publishes each year a report about aircraft accidents in the world. The latest one indicates these average figures:

- There are 3.3 billion passengers per year.
- There are 100,000 flights per day.

Over the last four years the accident rate decreased from 94 to 73 accidents per year.

In 2014, among these 36,500,000 flights:

- There has been a total of 73 accidents
- 12 accidents had fatalities (641 fatalities).

ICAO also publishes statistics which [can be viewed online](https://www.icao.int/safety/iStars/Pages/Accident-Statistics.aspx) according to custom criteria.

---

**Extracts from [IATA 2015 report](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/3049.pdf)**

[image]
<sup>(Source: [IATA report](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/3049.pdf))</sup>

**Period 2010-2014**

[image]
<sup>(Source: [IATA report](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/3049.pdf))</sup>

**Type and fatalities**:

[image]
<sup>(Source: [IATA report](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/3049.pdf))</sup>

**Geographical distribution**:

[image]
<sup>(Source: [IATA report](http://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/3049.pdf))</sup>

**ICAO statistics**

ICAO publishes statistics which can also be viewed using a graphical [web front-end](https://www.icao.int/safety/iStars/Pages/Accident-Statistics.aspx):

[image: ICAO accident statistics application]
<sup>ICAO accident statistics application</sup>

Data (["open data" series](https://www.icao.int/safety/iStars/Pages/APIs-Sample.aspx)) can be accessed using the [public API](https://www.icao.int/safety/iStars/Pages/API-Data-Service-new.aspx), but registration is required.