# How often are passenger oxygen masks deployed?

Tags: commercial-aviation, emergency, passenger, oxygen, oxygen-mask

In commercial passenger aviation, how frequent (or infrequent) is the case that oxygen masks deploy?

Please include links to statistics.

Comment: So infrequently that any statistics, if they exist, will be meaningless.

Comment: Not statistically significant, almost no matter how you slice it. Flying Hours/Deployments, Flights/Deployments, Aircraft/Deployments...

Comment: @RalphJ: Opinion, because, in my opinion, there is no mandatory notification for such event.

Comment: @RalphJ Are you expecting an answer which is not opinion based?  Any answer, since there will be no meaningful measures, must be opinion based.  I'll kick it off.  In my opinion, once every 12.7 million person miles.

Comment: @mins Couldn't one work out an upper bound by looking at, e.g., cabin pressure loss? http://www.avherald.com/h?search_term=Cabin+pressure&opt=256&dosearch=1&search.x=-862&search.y=-106

Comment: @Keepthesemind: In that case it would be appropriate to change the question and ask directly for pressure loss events. It would be less ambiguous (e.g. the crew can deploy masks by accident by pressing a button in the flight deck, regardless of the pressure.)

Comment: I'd be willing to bet serious money that there are far more deployments from hard landings and accidental deployments than from loss of pressurization. I'm embarrassed to admit it, but I made a hard landing in a 727 back in the 1980s that dropped a few masks in the back, and once while flying right-seat in a Citation, the left-seat guy accidentally deployed the masks. Neither I nor, to the best of my knowledge, any of my flying acquaintances ever experienced a loss of pressurization resulting in a deployment.

Comment: This is a good question. In my regular training I have to provide an answer to the underlying question (how frequent are aircraft depressurizations?) and in extensive research I have not been able to come up with a concrete answer, either current or historical.

Comment: helpful post http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34177/how-likely-could-there-be-a-loss-of-cabin-pressure

Answer (score 5):

Very, very rare, probably in the range of sinlge digits per 100,000 flights (for major first-world airlines, perhaps higher elsewhere).

I'll try to get you a more numeric answer tomorrow.

Posting an answer now so that I can edit it, evem if the question gets closed between now and then.

"Opinion based", horsefeathers!

Comment: try to help you: militar: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15945394

Comment: australia: https://www.atsb.gov.au/publications/2006/b20060142/ and https://flightsafety.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/asw_oct06_p33-41.pdf (accidents per year)

Comment: canada: depressurization: http://www.bst-tsb.gc.ca/eng/stats/aviation/2012/ss12.asp#sec4

Comment: finaly: researching in the NTSB records, 01/01/2011 to 31/12/2016, there were 12 itens for "oxygen masks".