# Amount of fuel consumed

Tags: aircraft-design

Airliners have 200 tons of fuel. Assume less than 10 hr flights.

An airplane flying all day consumes 4,200 barrels in 3 flights. Us jet fuel consumption is 1.5 million barrels per day.

Is it impossible to fly more than 400 airliners at any time?

Comment: How does fuel consumption factor into your question?  Do you think that somehow consumption is the limiting factor vs actual number of available airplanes?  If so please help us understand your confusion so somebody here can give you a better answer.

Comment: It seems so I understand.

Comment: There's one 0 too much in your barrels count: in 3 flights it's more 420 barrels than 4200. USA counts for more or less ⅓ of the worldwide consumption of jet fuel.

Comment: I guess you are a troll and you're going to be blocked, sorry because the question was actually interesting...

Comment: @sophit this person is an uber-troll

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not impossible to fly more than 400 airliners at any time.

According to [Spikeaerospace.com](https://www.spikeaerospace.com/air-traffic-around-the-globe-over-24-hours/#:%7E:text=Every%20day%2C%20some%2093%2C000%20flights,13%2C000%20airplanes%20in%20the%20air.):

> Every day, some 93,000 flights take off from approximately 9,000 airports. At any given time, there are between 8,000 and 13,000 airplanes in the air.

So in fact, a great many more than what you might consider possible actually fly every single day.

Comment: @mins, I'm just posting the first thing that came up on a quick Google search.  Still an order of magnitude over our local troll's "impossible" figure.

Comment: This figures are right. IATA statistics 2014: [100,000 commercial flights per day](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/21595/3201).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it impossible to fly more than 400 airliners at any time?

I invite you to count the dots.
From flightradar24, just now.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your math is wrong. A 737, for example, burns 850 gallons per hour, which is about 20 barrels. That is only 480 barrels per day even if the plane were running 24/7. There are larger airliners that burn more, but even a huge airliner like an A380 doesn't get close to 4200 barrels in a day.