# How many of the airliners that ever existed have been lost in flight?

Tags: airliner

Another way of asking this is: *Of all the airliners that have taken off and returned to the earth, what proportion have actually landed?*

Or another way: *If you were born as an airliner, what is the probability that you would die at work?*

I'm specifically interested in:

- airliners, being used as airliners (for example, not as emergency troop transports)
- hull-losses
- aircraft that took off and then crashed or were otherwise lost (i.e. not simply destroyed while on the ground)

We'd have to start with the total number of airliners constructed, which at a guess is a number in the region of 50-60 thousand - but perhaps someone has a reasonably accurate figure already collated from available sources.

Then we'd need to know the total number lost in flight - I guess it's just possible someone has such a figure.

It would be interesting to see how the figure changes for aircraft limited to particular eras.

### Related questions

A related question has been pointed out in the comments, [What percentage of airplanes are involved in a crash in their lifetime?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22591/what-percentage-of-airplanes-are-involved-in-a-crash-in-their-lifetime)

That's not explicitly about airliners, though in fact most of the discussion there seems to be based on airliners, and it contains some useful figures, including in one of the answers:

> That's a rate of 1.56 % aircraft with a fatal accident, or 1 / 64.

This is just an extrapolation from data about 2014, but it's a start.

However, it is based on incidents that kill people, rather than flights that damage airframes beyond repair, so it is about something slightly different.

Comment: Could you perhaps start with [List of missing aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missing_aircraft)? There are a few dozen entries there. You can filter that by what you consider to be an "airliner".

Comment: That's not actually going to help, but thanks anyway because it shows the question is not as clear as it could be!

Comment: If you want to include crashes, then try the [List of accidents and incidents involving commercial aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_accidents_and_incidents_involving_commercial_aircraft).

Comment: And how about aircraft that were lost while attempting to take off?

Comment: What is an airliner? How do you define the type of aircraft you are asking about? For example, does the Beech 99 "Airliner" count? If so, do you count a Beech 99 crash operated on a §135 mail run? I think as written this question is unclear, and possibly too broad.

Comment: Related 1: [What are the statistical probabilities of commercial aircraft accidents?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21593/) and 2: [What percentage of airplanes are involved in a crash in their lifetime?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22591)

Comment: @FreeMan Falling to the ground in small pieces is not "landing", nor is a catastrophic crash into terrain, or a flight into a large building. In the case of the airliners that were flown into the World Trade Center in 2001, I believe they were basically turned into dust and small pieces.

Comment: How are you counting botched landings (landing short, runway overrun, hard landing leading to hull loss)?

Comment: @Mark I think those would count. Obviously a line has to be drawn somewhere, and exactly where will be a slightly arbitrary point, but that seems reasonable.

Comment: For the portion that were hull losses, if you draw a graph of hull losses vs age you'll probably see a bathtub curve (of course would be more informative if that graph could also account for retired airliners).

Answer (score 14):

Okay, let's try for a first approximation. Some heavily-produced airliners; for simplicity I'm only counting jets. (ie, I don't want to try and work out how to deal with the DC-3...)

- [A320 family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A320_family). 7481 built, 35 hull losses (0.5%)
- [A330](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airbus_A330). 1330 built, 11 hull losses (0.8%)
- [Boeing 727](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_727). 1832 built, 118 hull losses (6.4%, mostly out of service)
- [Boeing 737](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_737). 9401 built, 184 hull losses (2.0%)
- [Boeing 747](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747). 1528 built, 60 hull losses (3.9%)
- [Boeing 757](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_757). 1050 built, 8 hull losses (0.8%)
- [Boeing 767](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_767). 1097 built, 15 hull losses (1.4%)
- [Boeing 777](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777). 1467 built, 6 hull losses (0.4%)
- [DC-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_DC-9). 976 built, 101 hull losses (10.3%, mostly out of service)
- [MD-80](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_MD-80). 1191 built, 35 hull losses (2.9%)
- [Tu-134](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-134). 854 built, 69 hull losses (8.1%, mostly out of service)
- [Tu-154](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-154). 1026 built, 69 hull losses (6.7%, mostly out of service)

This is a partial list, but it includes (I think?) every type with around 1000 or more examples built. It is thus probably representative of the general population of jet airliners. Total 29,322 aircraft, of which 711 (~2.5%) were eventually hull losses.

Now, not all hull losses are flight accidents - there are ground fires, accidents, military action, hurricanes, all sorts of other things - but the majority are. It's probably reasonable to estimate that the overall hull-loss-due-to-flight-accidents-so-far rate is thus a little lower, around 2%, but probably not much below that.

Now, it's worth noting that this isn't *quite* the same as

> If you were born as an airliner, what is the probability that you would die at work?

...because some of these aircraft *will* probably be hull losses, it just hasn't happened yet. If Boeing stopped building 747s tomorrow but airlines kept flying them, the hull loss rate would steadily creep up over time until all examples were either crashed or retired. So if you want to work from that perspective, the "eventual accident rate" will be higher. I've flagged the ones which are nearly completely out of service, where these will be approaching a "lifetime" loss rate - they're noticeably higher than the others.

Comment: I think your assumption of 'The majority of hull losses are in flight' is exactly the statistic that the OP is asking for more details on.

Comment: @DJClayworth Agree this bit's somewhat weak, but it's a figure that looks right after reading over the accident lists. It's hard to get a clearly defined list of *just* hull losses for any of these (other than the ones with only a handful, eg 777), but the WP page for the Tu-134 has almost all of them in a convenient table. For that particular type, ~85% of those were in-flight, counting takeoff & landing accidents, so it suggests the overall guess is in the realm of possibility.

Comment: @Andrew, you are using _Wikipedia_ for this? You should get better numbers at [https://aviation-safety.net/](https://aviation-safety.net/database/type/index.php). Unfortunately they don't seem to classify in-flight/on-ground either.

Comment: @JanHudec it's fine for basic numbers and a quick first-order answer, IME :-) the AS.net data is good, but doesn't have total built so can only really answer one side.

Comment: The rate for those types close to end of commercial service should be somewhat higher than the one for current types will be close to their end of service, because subsequent generations of aircraft generally tend to be safer to operate than their predecessors.

Comment: You missed every single type of airliner in the era that saw the highest density of accidents, the 1940s-'60s. Constellations rained down, DC-3s too, as did other types of that era. It was even worse in the 1920s and '30s, but the numbers were a lot lower as there simply weren't many aircraft around.